# Encadenamiento de promesas con querys de mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, promesas

Buen dia, quisiera saber como poder encadenar promesas que tienen consultas a la base de datos (con un callback dentro de la promesa).

En internet he encontrado que una promesa de javascript puede ser ejecutada de la siguiente manera:

```
function shareCard(req,res){

var SharedCard = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    console.log(1);
    resolve(2)
})
.then(element => {
    console.log(element)
    return(3)
})
.then(element => {
    console.log(element)
    return "Salida"
})
.catch((e)=>{
    res.status(500).send({ err: e});
 });

res.status(200).send({Hola : "Hola"})
}
```

Esto da como salida `123`

El problema viene en el siguiente ejercicio:

```
function shareCard(req,res){
let idUserSender = req.user._id;

var SharedCard = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    console.log(1);
    resolve(2)
})
.then(element => {
    User.findById(idUserSender,(err,userFound) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            console.log(element)
            return(3)
        }
    })
})
.then(element => {
    console.log(element)
    return "Salida"
})
.catch((e)=>{
    res.status(500).send({ err: e});
 });

res.status(200).send({Hola : "Hola"})
}
```

Donde la salida a este codigo es `1 indefinido, 2`
En otras palabras, la promesa le esta ganando al callback de la busqueda y justamente para poder realizar este comportamiento secuencial es que intento implementar promesas.

¿Alguien tiene una solucion o consejo para poder realizar esta tarea?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas cosas en tu código que no están del todo bien, pero es por la confusión que dan las promesas.

### 1 . El ámbito de `reject` está mal utilizado

Ejemplo

```
function hacerAlgo(parametro){
   ...
}
// parametro no es accesible desde aquí
console.log(parametro);
```

Traducido a tu código

```
var SharedCard = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    // alcance de todas las variables 
    // globales y resolve & reject
    console.log(1);
    resolve(2)

})
.then(element => {
    User.findById(idUserSender,(err,userFound) => {
        if (err) {
            // alcance de todas las variables
            // err & userFound
            // llamar reject dará un error
            reject(err)
        } else {
            console.log(element)
            return(3)
        }
    })
})
```

### 2 . En el segundo then no devuelves nada en caso de no haber error en la búsqueda (provocado por el error anterior)

```
.then(element => {
    User.findById(idUserSender,(err,userFound) => {
        if (err) {
            // alcance de todas las variables
            // err & userFound
            // llamar reject dará un error
            reject(err)
        } else {
            console.log(element)
            return(3)
        }
    })
})
```

## Solución

Mover la llamada a base de datos al cuerpo de la promesa y usar el ámbito de `resolve` o `reject` en el cuerpo del callback de la query

```
function shareCard(req,res){
    let idUserSender = req.user._id;

    new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        User.findById(idUserSender,(err,userFound) => {
            if (err) {
                // devolvemos el error
                reject(err)
            } else {
                // devolvemos el usuario encontrado
                resolve(userFound)
            }
        })
    })
    .then(user => {
        // todo fue bien y devolvemos nuestro usuario
        res.status(200).send(user);
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
        // hubo un error
        res.status(500).send({ err: e});
    });
}
```

Para terminar te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable de promesas

```js
(function() {

var print = (message) => document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML += message + '<br>';

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // simulamos una llamada a la BD con delay
    // tras tres segundos obtendremos la respuesta

    setTimeout(() => {
      // obtenemos un numero aleatorio de 1 a 10
      var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
     
      if(result % 2 == 0) {
         // en caso de par resolvemos
        resolve(" [Correcto] - El número " + result + " es par" );
      } else {
       // en caso de impar lanzamos error
        reject(" [Error] - El número " + result + " no es par" );
      }
      
     
    }, 3000);

  })
  .then((message) => print(message))
  .catch((message) => print(message));

})();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es encadenar una promesa con un API que tiene callbacks te recomiendo que uses [pify](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pify) o alguno de los métodos de otra librería de promesas como [bluebird.promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html). Ten en cuenta que estos sólo funcionan para callbacks estilo node, o sea

```
callback((error, data) => {})
```

En cuanto a porque tu código está imprimiendo `123` es muy sencillo. Debes entender que las promesas **cuando son encadenadas** tienen dos canales, el del `success` y el `error`. Una "cadena de promesas" en estado rechazado puede "recuperarse" y otra en estado exitoso puede "rechazarse" cambiando el canal en el que se encuentra. Vale recalcar que no sólo estoy hablando de promesas sino del encadenamiento de estas.

Una parte crucial de todo esto es el valor que retornas desde el metodo `then`

> Cuando retornas un valor ya sea en un `then` o un `catch` este automáticamente se convierte en una [promesa resuelta](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41). Puedes comprobarlo en el siguiente snippet (ojo necesitas un navegador compatible)

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('reason')
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log(1);
    return 2;
  })
  .then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
  });
```

Si te fijas estoy retornando un valor dentro de un `catch` y este se convirtió en una promesa resuelta y por lo tanto entró en el siguiente `then`. Un error muy común es pensar que retornar un error mantendrá la cadena en la sección del `catch`.

> Si quieres que tu cadena salte al próximo `catch` de la cadena [debes lanzar un error](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-42)

```js
const a = Promise
  .reject().catch(() => {
    console.log(1);
    throw new Error();
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log(3);
  });
```

Ves como salta de un `catch` al otro sin pasar por el `then`. Lo mismo no ocurre si sólo retornas un error

```js
const a = Promise
  .reject().catch(() => {
    console.log(1);
    return new Error(1);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log(3);
  });
```

En este caso imprime 1 retorna una promesa resulta y luego salta al `then` imprimiendo 2, omitiendo el `catch` o canal de error.

Resumiendo una **cadena** "rechazada" se puede recuperar en el siguiente paso sólo retornando un valor  u otra cadena que *resuelva* en cualquier cosa en su último paso y una cadena "resuelta" puede rechazarse lanzando un error o retornando otra cadena que complete en estado rechazado.

Segun la documentación [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById) retorna una `Query` que posee un método [`then`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-then) que la convierte en una promesa. No la confundas con el mismo método `then` de estas. Lee este [artículo](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises) para que entiendas la diferencia. el método [`exec`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) **si** te da una promesa. En lugar de esto

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    User.findById(idUserSender, (err,userFound) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            resolve(userFound)
        }
    });
})
```

Puedes sólo escribir

```
return User.findById(idUserSender).exec(); // Esta es una promesa lista para encadenar
```

Como nota adicional te diré que todo este comportamiento está definido en el [spec A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) de las promesas. Las promesas de los navegadores y de node en el servidor (que están definidas en el [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-objects) de javascript) son  conformantes con el A+. Hay algunas promesas (muy pocas actualmente) que no implementan dicho spec por lo que el comportamiento podría variar pero por lo general se trata de librerías obsoletas.